# How to resolve Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I don't know why I get this kind of error. It happens sometimes, and I suspicious of my code that still have thread running while I close my Application. So when I open again it happens.

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
StackTree :
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Where[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Susenas2015.ViewModels.Kuesioner.VMVsen15_KVal.SettingValidationAndRange(List`1 listTextBox, List`1 listCheckBox, TabControl tabControl) in d:\handita\Office\Project\Susenas 2015\Aplikasi Template Survei\Susenas2015\ViewModels\Kuesioner\VMVsen15_KVal.cs:line 430
   at Susenas2015.ViewModels.Kuesioner.VMVsen15_KVal.vSen15_K_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in d:\handita\Office\Project\Susenas 2015\Aplikasi Template Survei\Susenas2015\ViewModels\Kuesioner\VMVsen15_KVal.cs:line 846
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastEvent(DependencyObject root, RoutedEvent routedEvent)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastLoadedEvent(Object root)
   at MS.Internal.LoadedOrUnloadedOperation.DoWork()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireLoadedPendingCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Resize(ICompositionTarget resizedCompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.OnResize()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wpa`
```

My code here it is

```
    private void SettingValidationAndRange(List<TextBox> listTextBox, List<CheckBox> listCheckBox, TabControl tabControl)
        {

            List<string> listNotDeclare = new List<string>();

            foreach (var textB in listTextBox)
            {
                if (textB.Tag != null)
                    break;

                Metadata metadata = ListMetadataKor.Where(
                    x => "text" + x.Field == textB.Name // this line 430

                ).FirstOrDefault();

                if (metadata == null)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textB.Name))
                        listNotDeclare.Add(textB.Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    metadata.TabControl = tabControl;
                    textB.Tag = metadata;
                }

                textB.AddEvents();
                textB.AutomateFocus();

            }

            if (listNotDeclare.Count > 0)
            {
                Clipboard.SetText(string.Join(",", listNotDeclare.ToArray()));
                Dialog.Info("Ada beberapa Metadata tidak ditemukan data sudah dicopy ke clipboard");
            }

        }
```

When I start my application for my first time, it doesn't get any error. It happens when I open in 2nd or more. And if I open my application it would stuck in that code.

How I can solve this? I'm pretty sure that my Property `ListMetadataKor` is not `null`

And ListMetadataKor is instance of `List<Metadata>` object that I have created. It happens only in rare cases. And I don't know to solve it

### UPDATE

This is my code in image[image]

I fill `ListMetadataKor` with this code

```
BWHelper.Run((s, e) =>
{
    DataTable dataMetaDataKOR = ExcelHelper.GetDataTableFromExcel(
        AppConstants.FILE_METADATA, AppConstants.SHEET_METADATA_KOR
    );

    DataTable dataKonsistensiKOR = ExcelHelper.GetDataTableFromExcel(
         AppConstants.FILE_METADATA, AppConstants.SHEET_KONSISTENSI_KOR
     );

    listKonsistensiKor = Tools.ToolConvert.GetKonsistensi(dataKonsistensiKOR);
    listMetadataKor = Tools.ToolConvert.GetMetadata(dataMetaDataKOR);

    foreach (Metadata metadata in listMetadataKor)
    {
        metadata.Range.ProsesRange();
    }

}, (s, e) =>
{
    try
    {
        kor = new VSEN15_K() { Title = "Validasi Susenas - KOR" };
        kor.DataContext = new VMVsen15_KVal(rtSusenas.MasterRT, kor, this, listKonsistensiKor, listMetadataKor);
        kor.PreviewKeyDown += EventsCollection.EnterAsTabPreviewKeyDown;
        vmHome.HideLoading();
        UpdateMetaDataEntriKOR(RTSusenas.MasterRT);
        kor.ShowDialog();
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        vmHome.HideLoading();
        Dialog.Error(Ex);
    }
});
```

And then I throw the variable through constructor of my class

```
 public VMVsen15_KVal(
        MasterRT masterRT,
        VSEN15_K vSen15_K,
        IDaftarSusenas vmDaftarRTSusenas,
        List<Konsistensi> listKonsistensiKor,
        List<Metadata> listMetadataKor

        )
    {

        ListArtDetail = new ObservableCollection<ARTDetailVal>();

        this.ListKonsistensiKor = listKonsistensiKor;
        this.ListMetadataKor = listMetadataKor;
```

My tools konsistensi like this

```
public static List<Konsistensi> GetKonsistensi(DataTable dataTable)
{
    List<Konsistensi> listMetadata = new List<Konsistensi>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Konsistensi k = new Konsistensi();
        object[] required = new object[] { DBNull.Value, "" };
        k.Field = dataTable.Rows[i][FIELD].ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(k.Field)) continue;
        k.Message = dataTable.Rows[i][MESSAGE].ToString();
        var obj = dataTable.Rows[i][ORDER];
        k.Order = !required.Contains(dataTable.Rows[i][ORDER]) ? Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Rows[i][ORDER]) : (int?)null;
        k.Page = !required.Contains(dataTable.Rows[i][PAGE]) ? Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Rows[i][PAGE]) : (int?)null;
        k.Perlakuan = dataTable.Rows[i][PERLAKUAN].ToString();
        k.RelFields = dataTable.Rows[i][RELFIELDS].ToString();
        k.Rule = dataTable.Rows[i][RULE].ToString();

        if (dataTable.Rows[i][LEVEL].ToString().ToUpper() == ("ART"))
            k.LevelKonsistensi = LevelKonsistensi.ART;
        else if (dataTable.Rows[i][LEVEL].ToString().ToUpper() == ("RT"))
            k.LevelKonsistensi = LevelKonsistensi.RT;
        else if (dataTable.Rows[i][LEVEL].ToString().ToUpper() == ("RTWARNING"))
            k.LevelKonsistensi = LevelKonsistensi.RTWarning;
        else if (dataTable.Rows[i][LEVEL].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("ARTWARNING"))
            k.LevelKonsistensi = LevelKonsistensi.ARTWarning;
        else
            k.LevelKonsistensi = LevelKonsistensi.Lain;

        //k.LevelKonsistensi = dataTable.Rows[i][LEVEL].ToString().Contains("ART") ? LevelKonsistensi.ART : LevelKonsistensi.RT;
        if (k.IsEmpty())
            continue;

        listMetadata.Add(k);
    }
    return listMetadata;
}
```

Comment: Check if `x` is `null`

Comment: I'm pretty sure `ListMetadataKor` is `null`, because error says that `source` parameter is `null`. Source is the enumerable you are filtering

Comment: @mrhands Check if `ListMetadataKor ` is null or not .

Comment: @mrhands Can you please highlight the line no. *430* of your code.

Comment: I only get this error in my release apps installed in client. I never gets this error in development. And for the first time it, it always successful run. but sometimes in other computer it doen't work. I'm still confuse because I can get what actually happen here.

Comment: @mrhands what is `ListMetadataKor`? How do you fill it with values?

Comment: @mrhands what is the type of `ListMetadataKor` ? It seems that for some reason it contains `null` values.

Comment: @mrhands in what case `Tools.ToolConvert.GetMetadata` will return `null`?

Comment: I think it wold never get `null` because I get the data from my resource excel spreadsheet I included it

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Error message clearly says that `source` parameter is `null`. Source is the enumerable you are enumerating. In your case it is `ListMetadataKor` object. And its definitely `null` at the time you are filtering it second time. Make sure you never assign `null` to this list. Just check all references to this list in your code and look for assignments.

Comment: I don't know how to check it. because it run in release apps. not in my development environment. So I think I have to make remote debugger first to know the real problems. But do you think that maybe my variable is still locating in memory with value `null`?

Comment: @mrhands I'm 100% sure that `ListMetadataKor` is `null`. You should start from `Tools.ToolConvert.GetMetadata` method and check when it returns `null`. I believe it returns null if table `dataMetaDataKOR` is empty. Looks like you should return empty list in that case

Comment: Ok.. Do you have any idea that my code fails to load in backgroundworker? I have loaded it using thread `BWHelper.Run`

Comment: @mrhands also possible problem is handling of exceptions in your BWHelper.Run method. What happens if there is exception in loading data tables or running ToolConvert methods? Do you assign `listMetadataKor` variable in that case? Or it stays unassigned with default `null` value?

Comment: It stays unassigned with default null value

Comment: my problem was with spelling It was case sensitive!

Answer (score 15):

> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: source

Above error comes in situation when you are querying the collection which is null.

For demonstration below code will result in such an exception.

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
IEnumerable<int> list = null;
list.Where(d => d ==4).FirstOrDefault();
```

Here is the output of the above code.

> Hello World
>   Run-time exception (line 11): Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: source
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: source] at Program.Main(): line 11

In your case `ListMetadataKor` is null.
[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JhUtyZ) is the fiddle if you want to play around.

Answer (score 13):

When you call a Linq statement like this:

```
// x = new List<string>();
var count = x.Count(s => s.StartsWith("x"));
```

You are actually using an extension method in the System.Linq namespace, so what the compiler translates this into is:

```
var count = Enumerable.Count(x, s => s.StartsWith("x"));
```

So the error you are getting above is because the first parameter, `source` (which would be `x` in the sample above) is null.

Comment: How can I resolve this? In my case, it is `@Html.DropDownList("Select Measurements", new SelectList(Model.Select(i => i.Measurement).Distinct().ToList()), new { @class = "form-control" })`. I am passing my model as `IEnumerable<mymodel>` in the view. Please explain :)

Comment: Well my guess is that Model is null. Are you passing it in when you return the view? `e.g. return View("ViewName", model);`

Comment: I wasn't passing any model. Now got it. I'll thank you by upvoting your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   value

This error message is not very helpful!

You can get this error in many different ways.  The error may not always be with the parameter name: **value**.  It could be whatever parameter name is being passed into a function.

As a generic way to solve this, look at the stack trace or call stack:

```
Test method GetApiModel threw exception: 
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
    at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
```

You can see that the parameter name `value` is the first parameter for `DeserializeObject`.  This lead me to check my AutoMapper mapping where we are deserializing a JSON string.  That string is null in my database.

You can change the code to check for null.

Answer (score 1):

my problem was with spelling It was case sensitive! Few of the columns were sorting properly and rest were throwing this error!